# 'Il s'agit plutôt' dans ce contexte

Tags: traduction, verbes

J'ai lu cette phrase dans une vidéo:
« S'engager pour un monde meilleur quand il s'agit plutôt de l’air droit dans le mur, c’est chaud. »

Je ne la comprends pas. Il me semble que c'est à cause de « il s'agit plutôt », que je comprends normalement mais pas dans ce contexte.

Comment: Ce n'était donc pas *s’engager pour un monde meilleur quand il a plutôt l’air d’aller droit dans le mur, c’est chaud* ??

Comment: Cette suite de mots telle qu'elle est retranscrite ne veut rien dire et il s'agit vraisemblablement d'un erreur de sous titrage. Si c'est une vidéo vue en ligne (par exemple youtube) les erreurs sont très fréquentes, elles sont souvent faites par des automates, et quand elles sont faites par des humains et qu'elles proviennent de source non vérifiée les erreurs sont aussi fréquentes, que ce soit dans l'orthographe ou même dans la compréhension de l'oral. Donc merci de **donner la source exacte** d'où sont repris ces mots.

Comment: @Toto Personnellement je pense que c'était  à celui qui a posé la question de corriger la citation. On peut penser que c'est la proximité de « de l’air » avec « il s'agit plutôt » qui devait le gêner. Du plus comme on lui a posé la question la moindre des choses aurait été de le laisser répondre.

Comment: @Laure: Rectifie si tu le souhaite.

Comment: @Toto Je l'ai fait - puisque tu m'y autorises. Corriger les fautes de français c'est normal (on aide) mais là il s'agit d'autre chose : un manque de référence.

Answer (score 1):

Clairement c'est du langage parlé de très mauvaise qualité mais qu'on trouve partout sur internet. Il y a une sorte de compactage d'idées implicites (mais pas pour tout le monde).
Il y a trois parties distinctes:
"S'engager pour un monde meilleur": le sens est assez clair.
"quand il s'agit plutôt d'aller droit dans le mur": cette partie n'a en fait rien à voir grammaticalement avec la précédente. On donne ici une analyse supposée de la marche du monde, en disant en gros que tous les efforts (au lieu d'aller dans une direction "meilleure") vont vers une dégradation.
Autrement dit, le "il s'agit plutôt" marque ici une forme très maladroite d'opposition entre un état souhaité (monde meilleur) et un état constaté (direction dangereuse voire fatale).
Le "c'est chaud" conclut l'analyse en soulignant la difficulté du projet.